# IRepository pattern with generic Factory pattern

Tags: c#, generics, factory-pattern, irepository

I have the following DBML modification (i'm using Linq to SQL as a DAL).

```
public interface ILinqSQLObject { }

// these are objects from SQL Server mapped into Linq to SQL
public partial class NEWDEBT : ILinqSQLObject { }
public partial class OLDDEBT : ILinqSQLObject { }
public partial class VIPDEBT : ILinqSQLObject { }
```

With that i can manipulate my Linq objects more properly on other areas.

I've just done an IRepository pattern implementation.

```
public interface IDebtManager<T>
    {
        IQueryable<T> GetAllDebts();
        IQueryable T GetSpecificDebt(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
        void Insert(T debt);
        // other methods
    }

public class DebtManager<T> : IDebtManager<T> where T : class, ILinqSQLObject 
    {
        DebtContext conn = new DebtContext();
        protected System.Data.Linq.Table<T> table;

        public DebtManager()
        {
            table = conn.GetTable<T>();
        }

        public void Insert(T debt)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public IQueryable<T> GetSpecificDebt(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return table.Where(predicate);
        }

        public IQueryable<T> GetAllDebts()
        {
            return table;
        }
    }
```

And that works flawlessly. But, there are sometimes that i don't know, on compilation time, which specific table i'll be using. For that i tried to create a simple generic factory for my DebtManager.

```
public static class DebtFactoryManager
{

    public static DebtManager<ILinqSQLObject> GetDebtManager(string debtType) 
    {
        switch (debtType)
        {
            case "New Client":
                return new DebtManager<NEWDEBT>();
            case "Old Client":
                return new DebtManager<OLDDEBT>();
            case "VIP Client":
                return new DebtManager<VIPDEBT>();
            default:
                return new DebtManager<NEWDEBT>();
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

However it doesn't work. It says that i cannot 'implicity convert `DebtManager<NEWDEBT>` to `DebtManager<ILinqSQLObject>`', but if NEWDEBT implements ILinqSQLObject, why isn't the compiler recognizing it? Obviously i'm doing some mistake but i can't see it.

Comment: Is this sctual code? I think the static factory method is missing a name.

Comment: I accidentally removed its name. I've just edit it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is caused by the fact that generics do not implicitly support covariance; that is, treating a specific generic parameter type as if it were one of its base types.

Couple ways around this. First, you can define a non-generic DebtManager base class that the generic DebtManager inherits from, and return that. Second, you can define a generic interface that DebtManager implements; generic interfaces CAN be defined to be covariant, by using the keyword `out` before the generic type parameter.

**EDIT:** Let's go back to the primary need. You may not know, at compile-time, what type of object you will be required to work with and therefore you don't know which Repository you need. Might I suggest, then, that instead of a Repository-per-table architecture, you use a Repository-per-database. DebtManager is already generic to any Linq to SQL type; why not then make the methods generic as well, allowing them to be generic from call to call?

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T:class, ILinqSqlObject
{
    IQueryable<TSpec> GetAllDebts<TSpec>() where TSpec : T;
    IQueryable<TSpec> GetSpecificDebt<TSpec>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TSpec, bool>> predicate) where TSpec : T;
    void Insert<TSpec>(TSpec debt) where TSpec:T;
    // other methods
}

interface IDebtObject : ILinqSqlObject

public interface IDebtManager:IRepository<IDebtObject> { }

public class DebtManager:IDebtManager
{
    DebtContext conn = new DebtContext();

    public DebtManager()
    {            
    }

    public void Insert<T>(T debt) where T:IDebtObject
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IQueryable<T> GetSpecificDebt(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) where T:IDebtObject
    {
        return conn.GetTable<T>().Where(predicate);
    }

    public IQueryable<T> GetAllDebts<T>() where T:IDebtObject
    {
        return conn.GetTable<T>();
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, but `out` works only if all properties, fields and methods are readonly or have `out` parameters.

Comment: @KeithS Holy sh.. man, you're a genius! Your first work around worked flawlessly. Believe me, i was trying to do this for a loong time. That seemed way better than defining the interface to be covariant through out. Is there a situation where having a covariant interface is better than your first work around?

Comment: Well the first workaround basically hides the fact that the collection is generic. If you need to know that the object is generic to a type (for instance, to get/set child objects of the generic type) then it isn't the best plan. In your case, you don't know which table the DebtManager is pointed to unless you keep track of it another way, or reflect into the type and examine its generic member.

Comment: @KeithS i've tested it here. I see that i can't get the methods defined by the generic DebtManager. I believe i should use the second workaround then, right? Just what you said above. Without knowing its type i can't use any of my DebtManager methods to perform any database operations.

Comment: Well, there are deeper problems at play here. The deepest one is simply the fact that you don't know what you'll be working with at compile-time. The strength of generics is reusable "strong typing"; the type doesn't have to be known by the generic object itself, allowing the objects that *use* the generic to "close" it to a type that can then be enforced statically. If you have to go dynamic, as in *nothing* knows what exact types are in play until runtime, it's difficult or impossible to go back to statig generic typing.

Comment: If you need one class that can produce a DAO for any of the three tables, might I recommend another option; creating a Repository that *is* the DAO for all three. See edit.

Comment: @KeithS Thanks, pal, but that i already have. Actually i have lots of repositories for different kinds of tables. I thought it was possible to have a generic factory with a repository pattern. Seems it's not what generics are meant to be, since i'm looking for dynamic instantiation. I'll search a little more, but will check your's as the correct answer since you lead me to this understanding.